The number of strict up-sets and strict down-sets of a poset
I know that for an interval order $P$, the number of unique strict down-sets of $P$ is equal to the number of unique strict up-sets of $P$. I suspect that this is also true for a general poset $P$, but I cannot prove it in either case.
By a strict down-set of $P$ I mean a set of the form $\{ x \in P : x \prec y \}$ where $y \in P$. So in other words I am trying to prove that
$$|\{\{x \in P: x \prec y\} : y \in P\}| = |\{\{x \in P: y \prec x\} : y \in P\}|.$$
Edit: it turns out not to be true for general posets and I figured out how to prove it for interval orders.

If I didn't misunderstand the concept, it seems to me that the lattice $D_2$ has $4$ strict upsets and $5$ strict downsets.

@amrsa You are correct besides forgetting to count the empty down-sets. Thanks for pointing this out!
